# Download code works in Windows 7 but not XP SP2?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I have wrote a simple piece of code that downloads a file from a url. This code works perfectly in Windows 7, downloading the file at a good speed and maintaining a progress bar showing the download progress. However when I run the same piece of code from Windows XP SP2 it produces a .NET IOException
, it makes no sense to me why it doesnt work. It starts the same, completes the first read correctly and then throws the following exception on the second attempt to read from the stream :

```
 System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An operation on a
 socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a
 queue was full. ---> 

 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An operation on a socket could not be  
 performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)

 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
 at ServicePackChk.SrvPackChk.DownLoadServicePack(Boolean bWindowsXP)
 at ServicePackChk.SrvPackChk.CheckServicePackStatus()
 at ServicePackChk.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

CODE :

```
        Uri uri;

        if (bWindowsXP)
            uri = new Uri("http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/3/0/d30e32d8-418a-469d-b600-f32ce3edf42d/WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU.exe");
        else
            uri = null;

        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

        ProgBarForm pform = new ProgBarForm();

        updateEvent += new SrvPackChk.UpdateDownloaded(pform.UpdateProgBar);

        Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        ArrayList alBytes = new ArrayList();
        int nLen = (int)resp.ContentLength;


        pform.DownLoadSize = nLen;

        pform.Show();

        byte[] byExe = new byte[nLen];

        bool bMoreToDownload = true;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "XPSP3.exe", FileMode.Create);

        MessageBox.Show("Saving File to " + System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "XPSP3.exe");

        while (bMoreToDownload)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();

            int nRead = 0;

            nRead = stream.Read(byExe, 0, nLen);

            nDownloaded += nRead;

            updateEvent(nDownloaded);

            if (nDownloaded == nLen)
            {
                bMoreToDownload = false;
            }

            fs.Write(byExe, 0, nRead);
            fs.Flush();

            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        stream.Close();

        fs.Close();
```

Comment: instead of allocating `resp.ContentLength` bytes array, try to read in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

The file you download has over 300 Megabytes that you try to read in one go from the stream.

You better should read the stream blockwise, eg 4MByte blocks.

Comment: Its reading in blocks anyway, I ask for the whole length but I get chunks of data, the variable nRead = 78288 for the first succesful read on XP, subsequent read throw the exception, so I cannot see this being a problem surely ?

Comment: whats the sizes of the subsequent reads? You could pass a smaller value than nLen when you read the stream though, just to see what happens.

Comment: The 2nd read throws the exception as do all further reads. I tried nLen - nDownloaded, then however the program just sits waiting for read to return and it never does.

Comment: try this `stream.Read(byExe, 0, 4 * 1024 * 1024);`